# How well does my second sentence connect with the first one?

Tags: expression-choice

I am not sure in what category this question will fall, if any. If it needs to be altered, I will alter it. The following is the ending of a piece of writing:

> I will make a difference to people's lives. There is no better reward.

or,

> "He will do an excellent job. For him, there is no better reward."

Here, "reward" is being used in the generic sense of "satisfaction." But does that come off readily to a reader? Would they connect that reward to the execution of an excellent job?

I'm interested to know if the different phrases in this ending are well matched, and if there is a better/more measured way to express the idea.

Comment: It's ambiguous, and it's not guaranteed that everyone will understand that *For him, there is no better reward **than doing an excellent job.*** Every deletion produces a possibility of ambiguity; some more than others. If you are concerned about it, leave the boldface phrase in and there will be no ambiguity at all.

Comment: @JohnLawler Please phrase your comment in the form of an answer.

Comment: upvoted; it helps to know that it makes sense. i was concerned if it sounds hyperbole or too extreme to call something the best reward (at least for my american ear). I however think the context can be very important here. In personal statement form of letters, one may be prone to say that "there is no better reward," which one may not do in other contexts.

Comment: It reads fairly well, to me. There's an old expression that goes, "There's no reward like a job well-done" which is the point you are making.

Comment: @Joe Black, I'm a bit confused how to operate here, twice now I revisited a question and couldn't locate the comment I'd left. That just happened, so I rewrote said comment, only to have the original reappear. What's up?

Comment: @Little Eva 'A job well done is its own reward' is the form I'm familiar with. Though as OP and others say in various ways " 'a task done well' being 'a reward' must be non-literal" (metonymy involved,with 'a job well done' doing service for 'the sense of satisfaction accompanying a job well done'), I'd agree that this licenses the deletion.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, yes, immediately after I'd added the comment I recalled several variations on the theme ... and then realized they had appeared in answers further down this page--I'd neglected to read all the posted answers/comments--I'm still trying to absorb the site and its protocols. yes, metonymy. Great word.

Answer (score 2):

> "He will do an excellent job. For him, there is no better reward."

This is a matter of opinion, really. When one speaks of work as its own reward, generally the sense of satisfaction comes from the **knowledge** that the work was done well; simply doing work, regardless of quality, isn't guaranteed to resonate with your audience as a source of satisfaction / a reward.

There is no **greater** reward is a [much more common phrase](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no%20better%20reward%2C%20no%20greater%20reward&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20better%20reward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20greater%20reward%3B%2Cc0) than 'there is no better reward;' use of the more common phrase will improve communication with your audience. (When the phrase is expanded from 'no better reward' to 'there is no better reward,' Google returns 'no ngrams found')

My suggestion:

> "He will do an excellent job. For him, there is no greater reward."

Here's [one more nGrams search query](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there%20is%20no%20greater%20reward%2Cthere%20is%20no%20greater%20pleasure%2Cthere%20is%20no%20greater%20satisfaction%2C%20there%20is%20no%20higher%20reward%2Cthere%20is%20no%20higher%20pleasure%2Cthere%20is%20no%20higher%20satisfaction&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20is%20no%20greater%20reward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20is%20no%20greater%20pleasure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20is%20no%20greater%20satisfaction%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20is%20no%20higher%20reward%3B%2Cc0) that might help with your choice of phrasing.

A final suggestion would be to add more clarity to the first half of the sentence. "He will" -> "He knows he will" / "He is certain he will". In that case, the final word could be replaced by 'comfort' in the event that that suits your intended message.

Comment: ngrams search query is interesting. I agree with your observation that the use of common phrase is perhaps better, albeit at the cost of sounding a bit cliched. I could think of a couple of other ways to express a sentiment which is not the same as "there is no greater reward" but makes a strong ending: "i am ready to begin," or "i am set to start"  etc. except that I have overused these in the piece (Note the edit to the OP). "ready to begin" also ends a certain dynamism, punch to the ending but i need some other words that are just as dynamic for the ending.

Answer (score 2):

As I am wont to say, "There is more than one way to swing a dead cat!" Meaning: You can word a sentence in a bazillion ways, and each way will say and mean something a little bit different.

Take your sentence:

> "He will do an excellent job. For him, there is no better reward."

Here are some alternate versions. After reading them, ask yourself, In what ways are they different? Does one of the ways communicate the meaning and shades of meaning you intend, better than the others? If so, you may have the key to wording your sentence, your way.

> - For him there is no better reward than knowing he did an excellent job.
> - Knowing he did an excellent job is reward enough for him.
> - He finds no better reward than knowing he did an excellent job.
> - His greatest reward comes from simply knowing he did an excellent job.
> - Knowing he did an excellent job is his greatest reward.
> - There is no better reward for him than knowing he did an excellent job.
> - Doing an excellent job is, to him, his greatest reward.
> - The greatest reward to him is having done an excellent job.
> - Having done an excellent job is his greatest reward.

Notice in the above examples I've conflated your two sentences into one. Feel free, however, to stick with two sentences if you'd like. Here are some two-sentence examples:

> - He will do an excellent job. That's reward enough for him.
> - Rest assured he'll do an excellent job. Excellence, not money, motivates him.
> - Excellence, not money, motivates him. That's why I know he'll do an excellent job.
> - You can rest assured he'll do an excellent job. That's his greatest motivation.

In conclusion, I could go on at length, inventing different ways of expressing the same basic thought, but in the final analysis, a great deal depends on the context in which the words are found (assuming they are part of a larger writing). Context also involves audience considerations and the effect you want to have on who is reading or hearing the words you're using. How does each sentence *sound* when it's read aloud? Is that how you want it to sound in your audience's ear and/or mind? Does it communicate what you intend it to communicate? Why or why not? I say, Go with your gut!

Comment: Reading it aloud is the first thing I did when I jotted down "there is no better reward" and more and more I read the last couple lines of the piece more-and-more it sounded like a job half-done. In fact, an ending like "i am ready to begin" was perfect except it's been overused and I can't use it again. I looked at several permutations of the "ready to begin" for example "all set on this path" "set to go" "set to start", but none of them seem to be as fluid, informal yet sincere and simple but clear as well punchy as "ready to begin." The word "ready" is seeming to be only one of its kind.

Comment: @JoeBlack: Now that you've edited your posting, I realize your exemplar sentence was about you! In that case, I kind of like the feel of my sentence (with a change in pronouns), "Doing an excellent job is, to me, my greatest reward." Putting the "to me" in the body of the sentence is a rhetorical flourish in the family called sentential. That means you interrupt a sentence's normal syntax and in so doing draws attention (in your case) to both "excellent job" and "greatest reward" in a way that normal syntax does not. Don

Comment: upvoted for suggestion. The idea you suggest about keeping it in one sentence but interrupting the flow is interesting. However in the context of the piece, the two sentence construction seems to make the right impact. It doesn't have to be something related to "there is no better reward." It could be something of the form "I am ready to begin," but I have used this ready to begin ending in a piece and need some other words to capture the expression.